# $(\frac1n \sum_{j\not=i} Z_j - \frac{n-1}nZ_i) \sim N(0, \frac{n-1}n)$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

In lecture, we proved that $\overline{Z}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n(Z_i-\overline{Z})^2$ are independent, but I don't follow one step. The proof is as follows.

$Z_i \sim N(0,1)$ and $\overline{Z} \sim N(0,\frac1n)$ and $Z_i$ is iid.

$Z_i - \overline{Z} = (\frac1n \sum_{j\not=i} Z_j - \frac{n-1}nZ_i)$.

$(\frac1n \sum_{j\not=i} Z_j - \frac{n-1}nZ_i)\sim N(0, \frac{n-1}n)$.

$Cov(Z_i, \overline{Z}) =\frac1n$.

...

I just don't understand why the variance of $(\frac1n \sum_{j\not=i} Z_j - \frac{n-1}nZ_i)$ is $\frac{n-1}n$. Our lecturer said that it is easy to figure out, but I can't. Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have a sign problem:
$$Z_i - \overline Z = Z_i - \frac 1n\sum_{j}Z_j = Z_i - \frac 1nZ_i - \frac 1n\sum_{j \neq i}Z_j = \frac {n-1}nZ_i - \frac 1n\sum_{j \neq i}Z_j.$$

After that, just use the independence between the $Z_i$'s:
$$Var\left[\frac {n-1}nZ_i - \frac 1n\sum_{j \neq i}Z_j\right] = Var\left[\frac {n-1}nZ_i\right] \color{red}{+} Var\left[\frac 1n\sum_{j \neq i}Z_j\right] = \frac {(n-1)^2}{n^2}Var Z_i + \frac 1{n^2}\sum_{j \neq i}Var\left[Z_j\right]$$

Note that the minus sign becomes a plus sign.

I guess that for all $i$: $Z_i \sim \mathcal N(0, 1)$. Hence $Var Z_i = 1$ for all $i$. Therefore:
$$Var\left[\frac {n-1}nZ_i - \frac 1n\sum_{j \neq i}Z_j\right] = \frac {(n-1)^2 + (n-1)}{n^2} = \frac {n-1}{n^2}(n-1 + 1) = \frac {n-1}n.$$

Answer (score 1):

Write it as $\frac 1 n \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} Z_i -Z_i$. The first term, call it $Y_n$,  is normal with mean $0$ and variance $\frac 1 n$. Hence $E(Y_n-Z_i)^{2}=EY_n^{2}-2EY_nZ_i+EZ_i^{2}=\frac1  n -\frac 2 n+1 =\frac {n-1} n$.